# lscape and supertabular in Latex

Tags: latex

I would like to put pictures into a supertabular table within lscape enviroment. The code is:

```
  \newcounter{themenumber}  
  \newcounter{classnumber}  
  \newcounter{imagenumber}          
  \tablefirsthead{  
    \hline  
    \backslashbox{Concept}{Class} &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Class 0} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Class 1} \\ %\textbf{A} & \textbf{B}\\  
    \hline}  
  \tablehead{  
    \hline  
    \multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\small\sl continued from previous page}\\  
    \hline  
    \backslashbox{Concept}{Class} &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Class 0} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Class 1} \\ %\textbf{A} & \textbf{B}\\  
    \hline}  
  \tabletail{  
    %\hline  
    \multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\small\sl continued on next page}\\  
    \hline}  
  \tablelasttail{} %\tablelasttail{\hline}  
  \begin{landscape}  
  \begin{supertabular}{| c || c | c | c || c | c | c |}  
  \topcaption{Examples of All the Concepts. \label{tab:conceptsimgs}}    

    \forloop{themenumber}{1}{\value{themenumber} < 24}{  
        \arabic{themenumber}  
        \forloop{classnumber}{0}{\value{classnumber} < 2}{  
            \forloop{imagenumber}{1}{\value{imagenumber} < 4}{  
               & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../\arabic{themenumber}/\arabic{classnumber}_\arabic{imagenumber}.eps}  
            }  
        }  
        \\  
        \hline  
    }          

  \end{supertabular}  
  \end{landscape}
```

However there is something wrong with the result: no caption is shown, the height of the part of table in each page exceeds the page height and there is something extra unwanted at the last page. See images below:

[page1](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a5b1aaf6a5.png) [page2](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?4cacf78896.png) [page3](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?ec3344fa71.png) [page4](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?29a1edbb21.png)

How to fix the problems? Thanks and regards!

---

Update:

All the problems remain when forloop is removed and replaced with:

```
    1 & 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../1/0_1.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../1/0_2.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../1/0_3.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../1/1_1.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../1/1_2.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../1/1_3.eps}     \\
     \hline

    ... % from 2 to 22  

    23 & 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../23/0_1.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../23/0_2.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../23/0_3.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../23/1_1.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../23/1_2.eps}
    &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../23/1_3.eps}     \\
     \hline
```

Any idea how to fix the problems? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use LaTeX or PDFLaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Might be the same problem as [forloop and table in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564728/forloop-and-table-in-latex/2564847#2564847)

Try to create a table without `forloop` — just copy-paste the same line enough times. If the problem disappears, it's most probably the same one.

Comment: Thanks! but the problems remain when forloop is removed. See my update.