# forloop and table in LaTeX

Tags: for-loop, latex

Here is the LaTeX code for my table:

```
  \begin{table}{| c || c | c | c || c | c | c | }  
  \caption{Examples of the concepts. \label{tab:conceptsimgs}}\\   
  \hline  
  \backslashbox{Concept}{Class} &\multicolumn{3}{|c||}{Negative Class} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Positive Class}  \\  
  \hline  

  \forloop{themenumber}{1}{\value{themenumber} < 4}{  
        %\hline   
        \arabic{themenumber}  
        \forloop{classnumber}{0}{\value{classnumber} < 2}{  
            \forloop{imagenumber}{1}{\value{imagenumber} < 4}{  
                & 0  
            }  
        }  
        \\  
        \hline  
  }  

  \end{table}
```

Something is wrong in the result however. There is some extra thing at the end of the table, as shown in here:

http://www. freeimagehosting. net/image.php?c702bfc838.png

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nasty one. I've created a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, see below. Try to compile this and take a look at the results.

The point is, you seem to be out of luck — `tabular` does not like the output of `forloop`, it cannot disregard the last `\addtocounter` command. Maybe you can find some other package for loops.
You should be able to figure out the rest from the code below, if not, write a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{themenumber}  
\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}
% this is your table (minimal example)
\begin{tabular}{| c |}  
  \forloop{themenumber}{1}{\value{themenumber} < 2}{x\\ \hline}   
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2cm}

% this is what you wanted to have
\begin{tabular}{| c |}  
x \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2cm}

% this is what forloop produces
\begin{tabular}{| c |}  
x \\ \hline \addtocounter{test}{1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```